# Resizing a block of text depending of its width

Tags: css

I have a block of text in an ePub, let’s say a poem, that should keep its configuration (line breaks). But I want the block of text to reduce or increase its size based on the width of the window, more like an image, without using @media.

Is there a CSS-only *fluid* font-size that will change depending of the width of its container? Can I have a block of text to behave as an image when resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about something like `vw` ?

Here is the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

You can do somethink like

```
.your_selected_selected_class{
   font-size: 3vw;
}
```

**A bootply**: https://www.bootply.com/DtGzANDZSD

Comment: I tried in my ePub and the font size changed from the original, but the text doesn’t change when I resize the window.